# tcpdump always filters my packets

Tags: tcp, packet-capture, tcpdump

I've been using tcpdump for about a month now, and recently, it has stopped capturing any packets that were not sent to or from the computer running tcpdump. I've stripped down my command to just:

```
sudo tcpdump -i en2
```

I've checked my interfaces with ifconfig, and en2 is in "PROMISC" mode. When specifying a specific host as a filter, I only see a few "arp" messages but nothing compared to what is actually going on in the network.

Any ideas why this would be happening? Much appreciated if anyone can offer some advice!

Richard

ps, sorry for the re-post, i wanted to register this time! (new to s.o.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what network equipment is used \ if there has been a change recently?

One possible explanation is that your computer is connected to a switch (and not a hub) the switch sends to your adapter only traffic intended to your MAC address, and broad casts (hence the ARP)

one way to check this is to send broad casts from other computers in the network (just use `ping 255.255.255.255`) and see if you can see anything.

Comment: Definitely no change recently, I'm on a simple home network, under a westell 7500 router. Interesting, when I ping another host (or ping *from* other hosts) in my network, I can see each echo/reply. I also see all data (http, ip, tcp...) to and from the computer running tcpdump, but nothing really from other hosts. (well now arp *and* icmp requests).

Comment: I don't know this router, but most routers I used do work as switches between their lan ports - so this behavior is expected. you may have an option in the router to decide whether it would act as a switch or hub.